# Suggest the right stack exchange community for certain tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, site-crossover

I think SO should suggest other Stack Exchanges sites for questions tagged with specific tags.

For example, all questions in SO tagged with [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) should get a warning suggesting the user to post the question in https://stats.stackexchange.com/ instead, for example.

[image]

"Machine learning" is in the **description** of the community as you can see above.

The idea is not to tell the user his question is off-topic at SO, but to try to help him/her to find his/her question quickly **suggesting** a more appropriate site based on his/her questions tags.

Comment: Questions that are tagged machine learning are usually **not** on topic for Stats.SE. Even when a question might be on topic for another SE site, does **not** make it off-topic on Stack Overflow. For example, questions about MS Sharepoint *can* be on-topic here if they involve a programming problem *with Sharepoint*, and such a question does not need to be asked there.

Comment: please see the screenshot above

Comment: Yeah, so? Question about *how to implement machine learning algorithms* are still perfectly on topic here.

Comment: Note that *CrossValidated is for statisticians, data miners, and anyone else doing data analysis or interested in it as a discipline.* This is not about *programming* machine learning, it is about *applying* machine learning to datasets.

Comment: What makes you think that a significant number of people get it wrong when they use the machine learning tag? Because that is what it would take for your feature request to make sense. I don't have the impression that the tag is causing problems to the extent we need to tell people to go look at Cross Validated every time someone uses the tag on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I usually suggest users that post their questions using this tag in SO to ask in cross validated and often they say thanks. I don't work for SO to perform this kind of analysis, of how many users get their answers about a specific subject in another stack exchange site. Also, this is a FEATURE REQUEST. I am just providing my feedback here. Do you have the numbers as well to say this feature request is not worth trying?

Comment: You don't need to work for SE to get such data. You can produce numbers on how often such question get closed using the [SE Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), for example.

Comment: So you're saying that to request a new feature in stack overflow, I have to download data, perform a whole analysis myself and submit here??? Are you kidding?

Comment: Feature requests do carry the burden of having to convince SE that they are worth implementing; you have a feeling it is useful, I have a feeling it'll not be worth it and lead to too many false-positives (and people asking programming questions on Cross Validated that should have stayed on Stack Overflow). But since you are championing the request, I am asking you to produce more evidence.

Comment: No, the data explorer gives you all the tools to do the analysis online. I did not say you *have* to do that, only that you *can*.

Comment: And people are downvoting this question because they had performed the analysis and figured out it's a silly request? :-D

Comment: I cannot say why people vote on it, no one else commented. Also see [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on Meta are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites, especially for feature requests. However, your request is lacking proper motivation and detail, perhaps people are voting on it to indicate they think the *quality* of the proposal is lacking.

Comment: How about communities such as "Drupal Answers", "Unix and Linux", "Ask Ubuntu", "Raspberry Pi"? Anyway, you're right. The people that are downvoting may be not the same people that make the decisions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with this is that you really can't tell where it belongs with only one tag. Even multiple tags may give you the wrong result. So, this would be more trouble than it's worth.

Now, let's say you ignored this. So, for example, let's say that all questions tagged with [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) will be suggested to go to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ because they seem off-topic.  Well, here comes a double meaning.  The tag wiki for [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) is:

> A recommendation system, or recommendation engine, is an automatic tool that recommends goods to a specific user. There are many examples on online commercial websites: Netflix or IMDB recommends movies, Amazon recommends books any many more, etc. The input of such algorithms are most commonly the past purchases of the user, the rating the user gave to other goods, the items that have been purchased together ("customer who bought this also bought..."), the browsing history, etc.

But, some users may not read the tag wiki and use it for software recommendations. Basically, what I'm trying to say is that you can't judge questions by the tags. They can have different meanings to different people and do not provide enough information.

Just as an added bonus, there are people who spam tags. So, that wouldn't go over well.

Comment: what we really need is to [Add a “Magic 8-Ball” feature to the Ask a Question page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1696/165773)

Comment: sure, but the idea here is just to suggest the adequate site and this is straightforward in some cases. For example, someone that is writing a question for stackoverflow about drupal can get a brief warning saying "your question is tagged with drupal, you may find better and faster answers asking this at drupal community, do you want to redirect this question to this other site?". I am not saying we must find the most adequate site for every tag.

Comment: @Leo How about a question like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993279/how-to-fetch-the-last-value-from-the-list-of-values-using-regex) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894082/cant-get-certain-css-code-to-work-in-drupal-7-site-on-ie-8)?

Comment: @Anonymous it's up to who write the question to post it at drupal community or not. As I've said, I am not suggesting to AUTOMATICALLY POST it at drupal community.

Comment: @Leo I'm aware of that, but what I'm saying is that you can't judge a question by the tags. An inexperienced user may move a perfectly valid question there because they were recommended to. There is already an on-topic list to the right of the Ask a Question page if they want to be sure.

Comment: @Anonymous of course he can, but at the same time, just because he does not know that there exists a drupal community, he is also wasting the opportunity to direct his question to the appropriate community