# That sure is a nice [minecraft] tag you have there. It would be a shame if anything happened to it

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

Inspired by: [Asking Minecraft questions on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310722/asking-minecraft-questions-on-stack-overflow)

We have 1,032 questions tagged [minecraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft).

As much as I love the game, the tag is irrelevant on SO. It's a meta-tag:

> [How can you tell you're using a meta-tag?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) It’s easier than you might think.
>
> 1. **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.
> 2. **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.** In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag [subjective] itself … is actually subjective. Ditto for [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? These tags are impossible to define by anything remotely resembling an objective metric. In comparison, the the meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and [javascript] are crystal clear to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

The tag itself doesn't say anything about the programming issue the question is (should be) about. It requires a language tag with it, probably along with some sort of library / api tag.

It may be time to send [minecraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) to the void.

Comment: Nooo. That tag is great for identifying bad questions. Adding that to my ignored tags list removed so much garbage. If we remove it, I'll have to start seeing it all again.

Comment: @resueman: Only proves my point that the tag should go. ;-) Ignoring bad questions doesn't make them go away.

Comment: How did you make “minecraft” look like a tag?

Comment: @GhostCoder20: `[tag:minecraft]`

Comment: @GhostCoder20 you can self-answer you know: hit that 'edit' link below the post to see the markup :)

Comment: @Gimby They don't have 2k, there's no edit link on meta posts.

Comment: We really should burninate this tag. I play minecraft religiously, but its utterly irrelevant to SO.

Comment: @approxiblue: users below 2k can suggest edits.

Comment: @approxiblue Second slightly more time consuming way to self-answer: don't ignore the help center! http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @Cerbrus: not on meta.

Comment: Oh, good to know.

Comment: So what tag should be used for programming to the Minecraft API? That's what I always assumed this tag was for.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Then the tag description should probably be rewritten. As it is, it's a description of the game, more or less.

Comment: @JonSkeet lets go the explicit way: minecart-api. That way it's obvious you are asking about the API, not the game in general.

Comment: @Braiam: That seems reasonable - is there already such a tag? Can we retag some of the existing questions (the ones that are genuinely about that API) so as to make it a reasonable precedent?

Comment: @JonSkeet no, there isn't. At least not about minecraft-api, but google-api, youtube-api, gmail-api, dropbox-api exists and are more popular that their non-api-suffixed counterparts.

Comment: Do we have a more specific precedent (other moddable software)? I see a world-of-warcraft tag, but it's small.

Comment: I can't think of any tag that would fit currently since the others (like Bukkit) are specific to using that software instead.  Would it be perhaps desirable instead to just rename this tag to minecraft-modding to at least get rid of the notion that one can ask questions about the game?

Comment: @Jon To clear things up: There is no Minecraft API, much to modder's disappointment. Most modding questions are with regard to third-party modding plugins / servers / APIs

Comment: Wouldn't the "Minecraft API" be the native console commands and settings files to a [unmodified] Minecraft server? Scripts can be created for that without the use of 3rd party tools. (*resulting in a modified server*) Though, questions regarding those kinds of things seem to be end up with a negative score when I scanned through it quick.

Comment: I could reasonably imagine someone being an expert in minecraft related tech, such as the internals for modding, the network protocol, common frameworks around it, etc.  If I knew about minecraft and wanted to answer questions about it, I wouldn't want to hunt through every language tag, I'd want to favorite the [minecraft] tag.  I don't see why this should be burninated, it's not a meta tag.  It's like saying [flask] is a meta tag because everyone could just tag the questions [python].

Comment: @davidism that's not the problem. The problem is that minecraft gives the impression that *any question* about minecraft, programing related or not, can be asked. And most of the times, the impression is more powerful that the reality.

Comment: @Braiam All tags must be assumed to be constrained by the context of programming. Any question not so constrained is inappropriate for the forum as a whole: it is not the tag's job to create that constraint. The `java` tag does not allow for questions about coffee simply because it exists. The site as the whole is constrained to programming (hence the rigorous close-question process): the question is whether there are legitimate questions about programming within the context of minecraft.

Comment: @NathanielFord "assumed", you said it. Humans psychology is all about perception, and having a tag about an off-topic or doggy topic gives the *perception*, *impression*, *idea* that the topic is allowed. They presume that if the tag exist is because others before them raised a question about the same topic, and was allowed, therefore theirs will be allowed too.

Comment: @Braiam I was using 'assumed' in the context of deciding whether a tag is valid. You must assume the tag is talking about the named concept _within the context of programming_ when deciding if it is a *valid* tag. Otherwise we would have to ditch `java`, `c`, `r`, `bash`, `brunch`, `grunt`, `facebook` and `python` all because they have common other meanings associated with them. The fact that some reader of the forum may mistake the meaning  is irrelevant: the rest of the site is built to correct this misunderstanding. Deciding tag validity based on common perception is too subjective.

Comment: @NathanielFord is funny that you mention those, because there was an [actual case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226637). But my point is being missed. From a human behavior perspective, the "context" is *their context*, and that change from one to another context. To give an idea: I have a problem mod-ing minecraft, I know its probably something to do with the code, I go to the place where all coders go, I write my problem (not?) and see, there's a tag for my problem, here's definitively the place where I should post this. The tag reinforce the idea that we cater them, while it's false.

Comment: @Braiam Now it seems like you're arguing that even valid minecraft programming questions should be disallowed? Is your objection that any minecraft related question is invalid on its face? (If so, why is this not true for Facebook?) Or that the name is insufficiently specific and invites posts that are invalid because it's not about programming?

Comment: @NathanielFord definitively the last assertion.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I think [minecraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) is for Minecraft programming in the broadest sense, in which case the tag is good.

Every question about Minecraft that is not about programming is off-topic anyway, with or without this tag, and should be closed for that reason.

You could change the tag to [minecraft-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-api), but as CubeJockey comments, there is no real API. You could change it to [minecraft-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-programming), but that seems a bit redundant for the same reason, and you'd have to rename other tags as well, like [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel), which also doesn't implicitly allow questions about the general use of the software.

Comment: Disagree. Any programming done for minecraft would be gamedev, so should be in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The fact that a question is on-topic on gamedev doesn't mean it's off-topic here. I actually agree with you, and [tried to make that happen](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267326/has-stack-overflow-become-too-big), but as you can see, I didn't get much support on that. Anyway, it's besides the point of the question and the answer.

Comment: "The fact that a question is on-topic on gamedev doesn't mean it's off-topic here" I hadn't considered that; thank you. Perhaps a [feature-request] would be for stackexchange to automatically suggest, "Your post looks like it would be better suited on <site-x>" edit: never mind. found [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267613/suggest-the-right-stack-exchange-community-for-certain-tags)

Comment: I'd vote for that.

Comment: Now lets all agree that we don't want a separate tag for each game that can have any sort of construction kit/api/framework. Imagine the list. Using this concept you can add any piece of software that can be altered in some way. No. This is for programming questions/tools/etc. You want to tag games - go to gamedev, it's not about whether we like Minecraft or not.

Comment: @Zloj Would you please name 5 other games that are modifiable to the extent with community support that minecraft is/has?

Comment: @Zloj my point is that not only is minecraft an immensely popular game, it can be heavily modified, in code. That code can be confusing to create/write. As such, a minecraft tag here is useful for those asking questions about said code.

Comment: @FuriousFolder TES III, IV, V . I'm not much of a gamer myself but there will be a much bigger list. Again, read my comment once more. This is the concept we are agreeing upon. Accept minecraft tag and you'll need to accept all others. What would happen then? Instead of real programming tags you end up with tags for actually existing software. This is NOT correct.

Comment: @FuriousFolder You're absolutely right. It definitely needs a community. This community is http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Zloj *oops*... How could I forget dev-supported mods? My bad.

Comment: Worth mentioning that http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ **has** a tag called "mods".

Comment: @Zloj There already are tags for lots of actually existing software, ranging from IDE's and tools to libraries, and also for software that can be programmatically altered, like Excel which I already mentioned as an example. I actually do agree that games should go on GameDev SE, but the status quo is that those questions are not off-topic for SO, and as long as that is the case, this tag also isn't obsolete. Whether gamedev questions should be off-topic altogether is a different discussion, which should not be fought here in this comments section.

Comment: Given that you can write programs to interact with Excel, and you can write and execute programs inside of Excel - both with Excel tools and with external programming languages - and these characteristics are true of Minecraft, what makes Minecraft distinct from Excel and therefore unworthy of a tag, whereas Excel is worthy? (Or Slack for that matter, that has two such tags?)

Comment: @NathanielFord Difference is that Excel has built in VB which itself is a programming language. Minecraft has a pickaxe, yeah.

Comment: @GolezTrol But IDE's, tools and libraries are all about programming, right? Asking questions about this is asking questions about how to program, while questions How to program Minecraft ask how to program Minecraft.

Comment: @Zloj Google 'computers built in minecraft'. Also note that many Excel questions are not about VB, but about Excel cell commands. I do not think that simply because Minecraft is a 'game' it should be discounted as not a 'programming environment'. Minecraft may have a pickax, but PHP has a `$`.

Comment: @NathanielFord sorry, but `Minecraft may have a pickax, but PHP has a $.` statement is not even close to a valid argument in current context.

Comment: @Zloj Sure it is. You're claiming you can't program in Minecraft, when you demonstrably can. As much as you can in Assembly or Excel. You cited the pickax as a reason why Minecraft isn't a programming environment: while the pickax is syntactical element of Minecraft that seems unnecessarily obtuse, so is the `$` in PHP. Neither is strictly necessary, but happen to be part of that environment, tools that programmers use to manipulate data. What is the _characteristic_ difference that makes Minecraft *not* a programming environment, however an awkward or indirect one?

Comment: May be relevant: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20219/is-minecraft-turing-complete  If Minecraft can construct turing complete machines, does it functionally differ from the [quartus] tag?

Comment: I thought Minecraft was based on ComputerCraft?

Comment: to mod for minecraft you really choose between minecraft forge (the modding api) and minecraft bukkit/cauldron (the server side software).

Comment: @NathanielFord this terrible. How can you not realize that any examples you give are the programmer's tools? PHP is a language used TO MAKE software. MINECRAFT is used to make fun and play - it's a goddamn END USER PRODUCT. You can not use minecraft to develop anything. Jesus Christ! IT IS `not` related to programming in any way except that it itself is program. You are either trolling or I don't know... If you fail to realize the above.

Comment: @Zloj I wrote an adventure game in batch. Sometimes it's fun to seek the limits of what's possible. Esoteric languages like Brainfuck are also just there for that purpose. Besides, programming tools are end user products too. And if IDEs don't count, I bring up good old Excel or AutoCad again, which are good end user products by themselves and still contain a macro language and API to automate the software. Anyway, you're still fighting a different battle. The question is not whether Minecraft questions are off topic. Also your tone of voice is starting to become unpleasant.

Comment: @GolezTrol I feel sorry for people who don't see a difference between Minecraft and Excel.

Comment: @Zloy Well, they are both based around rectangular shapes..

Comment: @Zloj There is clearly a difference between Minecraft and Excel (and indeed between Excel and Google Sheets). However, that difference is not "you can program in one and not the other". You can program in both Excel and Minecraft... and even PHP. I don't accept that 'Minecraft was marketed as a game' is a good reason to say it is not a 'tool that can be used to simulate in a 3d environment a Turing-complete machine and everything such a machine would do', or in short 'a programming environment'. That is too narrow a view.

Comment: A closing thought from the hacker credo before I abandon this conversation: you should use the best (or most fun) tool on hand, even if that tool had a different original purpose. This principle seems to full-throatedly support anyone who wants to program in Minecraft.

Answer (score 7):

> If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a
>   meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as
>   the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective],
>   and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you
>   nothing at all about the content of the question.

Too many things fail by this criteria if we interpret this too literally. Any library available for multiple languages would fail by this criteria.

> If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s
>   probably a meta-tag. In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag
>   [subjective] itself … is actually subjective. Ditto for
>   [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices to whom? Beginner by
>   what criteria? These tags are impossible to define by anything
>   remotely resembling an objective metric. In comparison, the the
>   meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and [javascript] are crystal clear
>   to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

[minecraft] doesn't fail on this category. Where it differs is on some details, but I really don't think that's what this second clause is about.

To see a difference, take this question: *"What are the best practices?"* That could spawn a debate for an eternity and endless questions just asking to clarify the meaning of the question. Even at the broadest contextual level, it's unclear. *"What is Minecraft?"* yields a pretty clear, unbiased answer. Tags like "beginner" are more about the perception of the person raising the question than the content of the question. The `minecraft` tag makes it pretty clear what the content of the question is supposed to be (I'm not saying "will be", but "supposed to be" -- the fact that bad questions are often raised in a tag doesn't invalidate the tag).

These two are all about addressing ambiguity at a broad level. The practical examples cited have little in common with the characteristics of the [minecraft] tag. There's little ambiguous about Minecraft.

To me the only problem with the `minecraft` tag that, say, makes it different from `unreal-engine4` or even `qt` is that it tends to spawn the worst kind of question traffic from very young and aspiring programmers who haven't learned how to ask proper questions, to study things formally and patiently, etc. But that traffic doesn't go away with the retirement of a tag. It simply spills out.